# Sum consecutive rows

Tags: sql, sum

In SQL I need to get the sum of the previous rows, but I don't know how to do it.

I have a column with the Id, Edition, Subject (they are filtered by this field) and Amount, and need to add a new column Total that sum the previous rows like the image below:

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: super hard to understand where you're stuck here. What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: You should tag your rdms. This will probably work, but it depends on which rdbms you are using. `sum(Amount) over (order by OrderId)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
SELECT orderId, Edition, Subject, Amount, sum(amount) 
    OVER (ORDER BY subject ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) sum 
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Same as I said to VvdL, it worked perfectly, thank you so much!